# How can i pull a file using SFTP in windows

Tags: windows, sftp

Can any one suggest me how to start working in SFTP?(Any books/web sites)

I have to create a batch program to pull a file from a url using SFTP in windows.

I have no idea about SFTP.

A batch program which pulls the file from a url using FTP is already existing.

PLease find below for the commands used in the above existing batch program.

```
set PgpID=gecorpcard
set FtpID=ftp.corpcard.com
set FtpUser=xxxxxxx
set FtpPswd=xxxxxxx
set FtpMethod=binary
set FtpGetUser=xxxxxxx
set FtpGetUserPswd=xxxxxxx
set PgpKeyID=0x29A6A1F6
```

Here the server name is `psftppgp201`.It means the file has to be uploaded into the server from the third party url.

Comment: are you sure you need SFTP? or just a secure ftp client, sftp is a wrapper for SSH filer transfers

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Putty package, i am pretty sure there is a CLI sftp included in it that can be scripted.

Comment: It's the PSFTP package

Answer (score 2):

Another SFTP and FTP client is [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/).

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for SFTP advice, but rest of your question is about FTP. SFTP and FTP are completely different protocols.

Basically:

- FTP is old, plain file transfer protocol. Passwords are sent unencrypted
- FTPS (or FTP/SSL) is same FTP protocol run over TLS/SSL encrypted communication channel
- SFTP stands for SSH File Transfer Protocol - a completely different beast. You can run SSH Shell or SCP over the same connection.

For details see http://www.rebex.net/kb/secure-ftp.aspx

FTP, FTP/SSL and SFTP clients for windows:
I would try either [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/index.php) or [WinScp](http://winscp.net/eng/docs/introduction). Both are multiplatform and work fine on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I use cygwin for that.  Includes a command line SSH / SFTP, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider is Syncplify.me FTP Script... similarly to batch scripts (and psftp for example) it allows the execution of scripts to transfer files to/from FTP(S) and SFTP servers, but instead of dealing with DOS-style batch commands, it supports 4 modern object-oriented programming languages.

More information here: http://www.syncplify.me/products/ftp-script/

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 there is a [OpenSSH Client](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) feature you can install

To enable/install the client:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
```

After the client is enabled you can use this one line commands in PowerShell.

*If you do not have set up key based access each command will ask for the password.*

To get a file from remote location:

```
echo "get /C:/remote-server-dir/remote-server-file C:\local-dir" | sftp user@hostName
```

To send a file to a remote location:

```
echo "put C:\local-dir\local-file /C:/remote-server-dir " | sftp user@hostName
```